# Is there a way to fetch data from a custom worpress table, my query fetches the last updated item on the table

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I am fetching **name**,**link**, and **date** from a custom WordPress database table to be displayed on one of my pages. How can I possibly fetch all the details?

I have successfully written the basic WordPress query to fetch the data, but interestingly the last updated (inserted) record from the table is the only one getting displayed. I believe the problem could be in my loop or something of the sort...

Here is my code:

```
function externalLinks($atts){
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'class' => ''
), $atts, 'externalLinks');
global $wpdb;
$table_name = "external_links";
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name");

    foreach ($myrows as $row)
    {
       $name = $row->name;
       $link = $row->link;
       $date = $row->date;
    }

    $html = '<ul>
            <li><a href='.$link.' target="_blank">'.$name.'</a>
            <span class="post-date">'.$date.'</span>
            </li>
            </ul>';
       return $html;

}
add_shortcode('externalLinks', 'externalLinks');
```

I expect the output to be **more than one** since i have a couple of entries in the  table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you're handling the data retrieved from the database.

In your `foreach` loop, you're assigning `$name`, `$link`, and `$date` the value of the current row in the loop. By the time the loop ends, `$name`, `$link`, and `$date` have all the corresponding values **from the last row**.

Change your code to this and it'll work as intended:

```
function externalLinks($atts){
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'class' => ''
    ), $atts, 'externalLinks');

    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = "external_links";
    $myrows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name");

    // Opening <ul> tag
    $html = '<ul>';

    foreach ($myrows as $row)
    {
        $name = $row->name;
        $link = $row->link;
        $date = $row->date;

        // Now we're adding the values of this
        // row to the $html variable, ergo to our list

        $html .= '<li>
            <a href='.$link.' target="_blank">'.$name.'</a>
            <span class="post-date">'.$date.'</span>
        </li>';
    }

    // Add the closing </ul> tag
    $html .= '</ul>';

    return $html;

}
add_shortcode('externalLinks', 'externalLinks');
```